# iOS NSArray inserting object at an index

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, testing

I'm looking at the crash log for a device that's testing an app and I see the following lines...

objc_exception_throw + 33

[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] +187

The code where this happens is below. appData is an NSDictionary, and I'm expecting imageUrl to be a URL to a png file on the internet.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= [self getNumberOfScreenshots]; i++) {
    pathToUrl = @"screenshot_";
    pathToUrl = [pathToUrl stringByAppendingString:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] stringValue]];
    imageUrl = [self.appData valueForKey:pathToUrl];
    imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]];
    [NSMutableArrayObj addObject:imageData];
}
```

What would cause this type of error? The error happens very rarely..could it be that imageData is sometimes nil because it fails to download the png image off the url, so that throws that exception when I try to add it to the NSMutableArrayObj?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, `nil` isn't allowed in containers; if the value could be `nil` that would be a problem.  You don't say which exception was raised though; the trace implies that an exception was thrown.  It probably describes the error more precisely.

Comment: Yeah add more error checking and reject images where `imageData == nil`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll add the error checking, I'm guessing it's the nil issue. i can't see exactly what exception is being thrown from the rest of the trace... the topmost line is  __exceptionPreprocess + 163

Comment: Add `NSAssert(imageData != nil, @"Invalid image!");` after the assignment of `imageData` if you think it should never be `non-nil`.  Then test it thoroughly and you should see if your assertion is correct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there may two reasons as you have not described error more specically

1) Actually your not allocating the memory to array

2) inserting nil value to array. To stop inserting nil do this:

```
 if(imageData)
 {
   [NSMutableArrayObj addObject:imageData];
 }
```